# svn moving all files, subdir into a new directory

Tags: svn

Newbie to svn. I tried loading a complete directory into svn

Eg:

```
svn import mynewcontent svn.something.edu/repo/portal -m "First import"
```

Where *mynewcontent* has many subdirs and files. Now I have a list of directories/files when I view `svn.something.edu/repo/portal` Eg:

```
File1
File2
Subdir1/
Subdir2/
```

However I want all those files to be in a directory mynewcontent on the svn.

Can I do something like:

```
svn move http://svn.something.edu/repo/portal/* http://svn.something.edu/repo/portal/mynewcontent
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that while that might work it's not the way to go. Re-import your project into the structure you'd like.

```
svn import mynewcontent svn.something.edu/repo/portal/trunk/mynewcontent -m "First import"
```

Don't forget to check it out afterward, the source you used for the import isn't a working copy

```
svn checkout --force svn.something.edu/repo/portal/trunk/mynewcontent .
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Not in one move, and with not only move, but

- Pure repository-side

  > svn mkdir http://svn.something.edu/repo/portal/mynewcontent
  >
  > svn move .../portal/file1 ... ..../portal/fileN ...portal/mynewcontent/
- Using WC in the middle

  > svn co http://svn.something.edu/repo/portal/
  >
  > svn switch ^/mynewcontent
  >
  > svn ci

  and remove outdated data from root later